# counting multiple columns that pass given criteria in excell

Tags: excel-formula, countif, sumifs

[image]

I really need help guys. Please, someone tell how to count how many times an agent passed the condition: **AIP Goals** please refer to the image. Agents who reached the goal for a specific metric (eq. r30, AHT, Dispatch Rate.. etc) have scores highlighted in yellow. I need to count how many times an agent passed a metric for each month.

I have been trying SUMIF and COUNTIF but I'm confused how to go about it.. I'm new to this and started about two weeks ago.. Please, someone help

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*($C11:$F11<=TRANSPOSE($B$26:$B$29)))
```

Entered as an array formula by using Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

This will give the July numbers for August and September simply add another SUMPRODUCT for those month each and add them together.  The columns must be in the same order as the goals.